# fatal: cannot use .git/info/exclude as an exclude file

Tags: git, laravel-5.3, gitignore

I have a Laravel 5.3 project with its `.gitignore` file but when I execute `git status` I get this message:

```
fatal: cannot use .git/info/exclude as an exclude file
```

I have executed this command to say where the `.gitignore` is

```
git config --global core.excludesfile C:\xampp\htdocs\codehacking5.3\.gitignore
```

But does not work.

Any idea please?

Comment: What is the contents of `.git/info/exclude`?

Comment: This might help http://365git.tumblr.com/post/519016351/three-ways-of-excluding-files

Comment: @Mahes Gareja the content is this# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~

Comment: Sorry I was wrong my exlude file "c:\xampp\htdocs\codehacking5.3\-git\info\eclude" is empty. its size is 0b.

Comment: **I have delete the file too and it's work now**

Answer (score 1):

Hi the problem was that that exclude file was empty for any reason. I have put it another exclude file with content and the problem was solved

Comment: What do you mean? Just fill something in the info/exclude file? My file contains: `# git ls-files --others --exclude-from=.git/info/exclude
# Lines that start with '#' are comments.
# For a project mostly in C, the following would be a good set of
# exclude patterns (uncomment them if you want to use them):
# *.[oa]
# *~`

Answer (score 1):

This may or may not address the above question directly, but since this is the question I landed on for a search for a similar error, I'll post the solution I eventually figured out here.

### First, my modified problem description (for the case I'm hitting):

My situation was I was attempting to build a tool to keep track of modifications to ignored files within a subdirectory, without checking them in to the repo.  While I didn't want to track the files (large data files, generated elsewhere and replaceable), I did want to gather checksums for them, update it occassionally, and track *the checksum file* in git.  As a piece of the puzzle, I was attempting the following:

```
git ls-files --exclude-from=data/.gitignore --ignored --others data
```

And this generated the very-similar-to-above error:

```
fatal: cannot use data/.gitignore as an exclude file
```

However, this seemed strange to me, as if I did an `cat data/.gitignore`, I could see that the file was there, readable by me, and contains normal content of a gitignore file.

Here was the catch: the `data` directory (and thus `data/.gitignore` was in a subdirectory of the main git repository, and the git command changed directory to the root of the repository (as shown by `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`)... And *relative to that directory*, the file indeed did not exist.

### Solution (for me, at least):

In the `--exclude-from` option, be sure that the filename you specify is relative to the root directory of the git repository (as shown by `git rev-parse --show-toplevel`)...  So, for me, changing the command (which I'm running from within `subdir`) to:

```
git ls-files --exclude-from=subdir/data/.gitignore --ignored --others data
```

... does the trick.

(For what it's worth, I figured this out by running `strace -f` on the `git ls-files ...` command, on a GNU/Linux system, and figuring out what was going on when it tried to reference the file... it was getting `ENOENT` ("No such file or directory") from `open(2)`, which I wouldn't have expected given my ability to access the file, so I figured it must have done a `chdir`, looked for that, and found it.)

Answer (score 0):

Just delete the file and you are done. See [here](https://github.com/msys2/MSYS2-packages/issues/748)

Comment: This is likely a valid answer in some cases... however, it's worth noting that it won't be a good idea in any case where someone has actually intentionally put items in that file with the intention of ignoring them... so...  please use with appropriate caution.  :)